# How to read database and convert result to HL7 file in Mirth Connect

Tags: java, mysql, mirth

I need help with reading `MySQL` database and converting it's result to HL7 file with Mirth Connect.

Since now I've added simple database reader as Source (picture below).

[image]

Data types in Summary tab are set like this:
[image]

Then I added Destination to be File writer and added path to folder and filename.

[image]

When I try to deploy this channel I get an error:

```
[2021-09-16 12:38:20,001]  ERROR  (org.quartz.core.JobRunShell:222): Job d7444f3c-249a-4e4f-b3b2-1862ac874cbc.PollConnectord7444f3c-249a-4e4f-b3b2-1862ac874cbc threw an unhandled Exception: 
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.mirth.connect.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseReceiverQuery (in unnamed module @0x2ca26d77) cannot access class com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl (in module java.sql.rowset) because module java.sql.rowset does not export com.sun.rowset to unnamed module @0x2ca26d77
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseReceiverQuery.poll(DatabaseReceiverQuery.java:195)
    at com.mirth.connect.connectors.jdbc.DatabaseReceiver.poll(DatabaseReceiver.java:134)
    at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.PollConnectorJob.execute(PollConnectorJob.java:49)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it :)

My solution was simple.. downgrade Java version from 16 to 15 and it will work perfectly.

Comment: http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/mirthuserguidev1r8p0/Message+Builder

Comment: https://forums.mirthproject.io/forum/mirth-connect/support/6686-need-help-converting-sql-to-hl7-using-database-reader?t=6505&highlight=database+reader+hl7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).